# Something like upper semicontinuity for finite fibres

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism between two quasiprojective, irreducible varieties over the complex numbers, such that the image of $f$ is Zariski dense in $Y$ and there is a Zariski dense subset $U$ (not necessarily open) of $X$ such that we have $\{x\}=f^{-1}(f(x))=\{y \in X: f(y)=f(x)\}$ for all $x \in U$.

Is $f$ then always a birational morphism? If not, is there a simple counterexample?

(Sorry for the first version of the question)

Comment: (I don't have enough rep to comment) You might find this question to be of interest http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73321/isomorphism-between-varieties-of-char-0. If you allow Y to be non-normal then you can finde _bijective_ morphisms which are not isomorphisms.

Comment: Consider $X = Y = E$ an elliptic curve, $f$ the map $\times 2$, and $U$ any infinite collection of points so that no two differ by 2-torsion.

Comment: Hi Carmelo, I am aware of this. When I say "birational morphism" i do not mean "isomorphism". A birational morphism is a morphism, which is invertible as a rational map.

Comment: @Hans: sure, I just thought the answers there could help with cooking up a counterexample. (I said it was a comment :)

Comment: thank you, i see. unfortunately, i did not pose the question, as i wanted to... i will edit now!

Comment: okay thank you. reading vivek's comment, i realized that the question was not stated correctly...

Comment: Now the answer is yes.  Here's a terrible proof: $Rf_* \mathbb{Q}$ is constructible, so it follows from your assumption that the fibre has the cohomology of a point over a (Zariski) open set in $Y$.  By semicontinuity of fibre dimension, the fibre is a point in some open subset of that.  By generic smoothness, I can conclude the map is birational.

Comment: One can also observe that the fraction field extension is a field extension.  The degree and transcendence determines the size of the generic fibers.  Here's a more geometric description.  If the geometric fiber over the generic point is a finite set of points, so will the general fibers over an open set (with the same number of points).  If the geometric fiber over the generic point is positive dimensional variety, the generic fibers will be likewise.  Since your Zariski dense set will certainly intersect this open set, that should do it.

Comment: @ Karl: the fibre over the generic point being a point is not enough to get birationality, and can't be: consider Frobenius.  (So characteristic zero is a necessary hypothesis in the question.)