# Morphism which is a bijection on closed points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

My question might be very naive.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be reduced schemes of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ a morphism of $k$-schemes. Let us assume that $Y$ is normal, connected and that $f$ induces a bijection on closed points. Can we conclude from these assumptions that $f$ is a local isomorphism?

If I assume that $X$ is also connected, may I conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: No. Let $Y= \mathbb{A}^1_k$, and $X$ the disjoint union of $ \mathbb{A}^1_k-\{0\}$ and $\{0\}$ with $f$ the obvious map.

Comment: Ok, I just edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $k$ is algebraically closed of non-zero characteristic $p$, then bijectivity on closed points is not enough (take the morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\,k[x]\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,k[x]$ corresponding to $f(T)\rightarrow f(T^p)$).

If $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic 0, then bijectivity on closed points [is](https://mathoverflow.net/a/264216/74900) enough (if your target is normal, that is).

If you do not make any assumption on characteristic, then the following [result](https://mathoverflow.net/a/73325/74900) is true. A quasi-finite birational morphism between integral schemes of finite type over an algebraically closed field, with target normal, is an open immersion. If your morphism is also surjective, it is an isomorphism (since surjective open immersions are isomorphisms). In particular, if your morphism is bijective birational, it is an isomorphism.

The reason why characteristics 0 and $p$ apparently behave differently is that only in $\mathrm{char}\,p$ you have this funny thing called purely inseparable field extension.

Comment: I was thinking of a field of characteristic zero, do this answers my question. Thanks!